# Loop a python function by given x time

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, loops, python-multithreading

In the function below, `my_module` won't stop until I terminate it manually. I need to know a method that terminates the function after 10 seconds and terminates it automatically. Then I want to run it again (loop).

```
import time
import my_module

def my_function():
    c= 1
    while True:
        my_module
my_function()
```

I tried threading but couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: you can use `time.sleep(10)` then exit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your requirement correctly; you wanted a way to automatically, terminate the module execution after 10 seconds whatever is the state of execution of that module. If the module is in between of some execution, then also stop it's execution. If this is your requirement, then you can try:

```py
import time
import threading
import my_module

def my_function(stop_event):
  while not stop_event.is_set():
    my_module
# Loop to run the function again
while True:
  stop_event = threading.Event()
  t = threading.Thread(target=my_function, args=(stop_event,))
  t.start()
  time.sleep(10)  # Let the function run for 10 seconds
  stop_event.set()  # Signal the function to stop
  t.join()
```

***[CODE DEMO](https://replit.com/@msankrit/AgreeableStrictConfig#main.py)***

Answer (score 0):

You can use several ways but may they are not rational. These things went in my mind:

1. You can have a **base** module in python and run this file python module by using **os library**: os.system("python yourFile.py") and set this in a for loop or while
2. Use Class: In the class implement my_function and at the end of use of this class try to call __ del __(self), reference : [Constructor and destructor](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/destructors-in-python/)
3. try to work with cronjob or make a bat or bash script set timer and try to run your module
4. Try this with multi threading:

> ```
> import time
> import threading
>
> second =0
> def timer():
>    global second
>    while True:
>       time.sleep(1)
>       second +=1
>
> def module_function():
>     
>    while second<=10:
>       print("hi")
>    print("finish")
>     
>
> t1 = threading.Thread(target=module_function  )
> t2 = threading.Thread(target=timer  )
> t1.start()
> t2.start()
> ```